# Creating and designing Air Trafic Control System

Tags: database-recommendation, database-design

I'm having a class about Database management system, and the prof. gave us a project regarding Air traffic controller system, exact question is "Design and create a system which can manage informations of Air Traffic Control System, summarize entities and how system works?"

im not asking you to do this for me, but im desperate, because i dont know how air traffic control system work and what my database should include.

i have limited time, Thanks in advance.

Comment: this is all details given to me, and professor ask for very long answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a tough one, if only there was a way to find things like that online.

http://tinyurl.com/q7zxplh

Make a list of the high level objects that need, such as planes, airports, routes, people, roles, etc. Then figure out how they are related, how you identify each object and what attributes they would have.

Comment: that helped me a lot, becasue of lack of reputation cant vote up for you, but it deserve. thank you very much.

Comment: Your welcome. Also think about the fact that some of the relationships are many to many relationships. For example pilots fly on multiple planes, each plane has more than one pilot. Planes fly multiple routes, each route is flown by more than one plane. To do a many to many relationship between two tables you usually have a common table with the primary key from both tables.

Comment: @Gandolf989 that's even better, thank you, now i have entities in my hand, i will create relationships and ER diagram and for radar image i think graph database will work just fine.

Comment: Glad to hear that you are making progress.